# How can I run docker commands inside Dockerfile for integrating into jenkins pipeline?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, k6

I'm trying to integrate grafana/k6 tests into the Jenkins pipeline, for that I have to integrate docker build and run commands into the Dockerfile. I was trying to do something like this:

```
FROM golang:1.18-alpine as builder

WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/go.k6.io/k6
ADD . .

RUN apk --no-cache add build-base git && \
    go install go.k6.io/xk6/cmd/xk6@latest && \
    CGO_ENABLED=1 xk6 build \
        --with github.com/grafana/xk6-sql \
        --output /tmp/k6 

# Build a custom k6 Docker image
RUN apk add --no-cache docker \
    && docker build -t grafana/k6-for-sql:latest .

# Create image for running your customized k6
FROM alpine:3.15

RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates \ 
    && adduser -D -u 12345 -g 12345 k6

COPY --from=builder /tmp/k6 /usr/bin/k6

USER 12345
WORKDIR /home/k6

# Run tests using custom k6 Docker image
CMD ["docker", "run", "--rm", "-i", "grafana/k6-for-sql", "run", "-", "<tests/test1.js", "--insecure-skip-tls-verify"]
```

but it throws this **error**: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache docker     && docker build -t grafana/k6-for-sql:latest .]: exit code: 1